# Shortcut for dropdown menu in Visual Code when highlighting JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm coding React in Visual Code and while trying to copy/paste a section of my code, I pressed the wrong combo of buttons and got a dropdown menu. It had about ten items on it, but all I remember seeing is an item that had "Destructure JavaScript" in it. It looked like a really interesting dropdown, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I pressed to get to it.

I have ESLint, JavaScript (ES6) code snippets, and React Native Tools, extensions installed, among others.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> when highlighting the code:

[image: dropdown menu]